# How to save dynamic form to database / edit form back

Tags: javascript, html, css, sql, forms

I've made myself a dynamic form builder using jquery ui that the the user can drag form inputs to wherever they like on the screen and create a report. Now I'm looking to save this to a SQL database. What would be the best way in going about saving the layout of this form and creating a database table from it that the user can then fill in reports and submit them to the database. 
How would I go about saving the HTML elements styles like transformations etc. I'd need these as I would like to be able to take an existing form and recreate it if it needs anything to be added/removed.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

How about arrange its fields and data into XML format or JSON then save it to database. You can use XML datatype column for XML format and varchar for JSON in Database.